# Como obtengo un array de una consulta de una sola columna? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array, mysqli

Quería saber si es posible obtener un array con los resultados de una consulta de una sola columna, ya que las funciones fetch_assoc(), fetch_row(), etc. devuelven de una fila y no de una columna.
Por ejemplo yo tengo el codigo:
`$query = $con->query("SELECT pid FROM tabla WHERE tid = 2");`
y quiero obtener un array de todos los pid donde el tid es 2, como lo obtengo?
Porque con los fetch() no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta donde tengo conocimiento, no se puede hacer directamente con alguna instrucción, ya que `$con->query` siempre va a traer un objeto con filas de registros, independientemente de la cantidad de columnas que solicitaste.

De todas formas, hacer lo que pides es bastante simple:

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT pid FROM tabla WHERE tid = 2");
$col_values = array();
while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $col_values[] = $result['pid'];
}
```